# How to make a post request from array of object with Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

My endpoint only accept only 1 object

```
Axios.post('www.url.com', { 
    giftAGift: false, 
    productId: "1030567", 
    quantity: 1, 
    storeId: 0, 
    variantId: ""
})
```

What I have is an array of object

```
let object = [{"giftAGift": false, "productId": "1234", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "12345", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "123456", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "`123456", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}]
```

What is the best way to make a post request when I want to send all data when I press only 1 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you must loop through the array and make an API call for each.

```js
let array = [{"giftAGift": false, "productId": "1234", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "12345", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "123456", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "`123456", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}]


array.forEach((obj) => {
  Axios.post('www.url.com', obj);
})
```

**Edit.** Using `Promise.allSettled`

```js
const promises = array.map((obj) => {
  return Axios.post('www.url.com', obj).then((response) => response.data);
});

Promise.allSettled(promises)
.then(() => ...)
.catch(() => ...)
.finally(() => ...)
```

Comment: @Idruskis Is there anyway for me to use `Promise.all`

Comment: Yes. Edited my answer. Just a note, it's pseudo code, so try to use it just as an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well its not good practice because you are inserting multiple records at a time. You should make multiple insert backend route for handling this.
So after this in one API call you can insert e.g., 30 records instead of 30 multiple requests.

But if you still want to make multiple requests then you can done job using following code:

```js
let array = [{"giftAGift": false, "productId": "1234", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""},
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "12345", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""},
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "123456", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""},
 {"giftAGift": false, "productId": "`123456", "quantity": 1, "storeId": 0, "variantId": ""}]


let arr=arr2.map((obj)=>Axios.post('url.com', obj));

let promise=Promise.allSettled(arr).then((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```